# Can trim statsmodels result for serialization?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm trying to build a distributed on-demand modeling production system and want to keep hundreds of thousands of small models in memory (and also transfer them to databases and between processes). I'm looking at statsmodels.

I'm mostly interested only in being able to save the model's coefficients and call predicts on the model.

It looks like statsmodels contains TONS of additional information (O(original data size)) that's simply not needed for this use case. The serialized size is some megabytes, while the size of the coefficients is only a few bytes. This fills my databases and kills distributed processing and cacheing performance where a lot of time is spent simply serializing and deserializing. Removing the non-coefficient data will likely result in a two orders of magnitude speedup, by keeping two orders of magnitude more models in memory.

In statsmodels, is there a general way:

- I can ask for the non-output-coefficient data to not be generated, or
- delete it from the object, or
- extract the coefficients (which is easy) AND a way to use them to make a predict (which seems less easy)

I'm using a variety of statsmodels models, but mostly GLM and Logit.

I doesn't look trivial. The result objects reference the model objects, which reference the original data. I can't make it work for an individual model, but (by deleting fields one by one). But is there are general purpose way that works for all models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Statsmodels has a `remove_data` method in the results classes that was added for exactly this purpose. First, most results are lazily computed, so after calling fit, the returned results instance does not yet contain many results statistics. However, it holds a reference to the model and the underlying data to compute those results statistics on demand. For example, calling `results.summary()` needs to compute many or most of them.

If we do not need to compute those statistics either because we already have all those we want or we only want to do prediction, then we can drop all large arrays and data to reduce the memory requirement. This is done by calling `results.remove_data()`.

http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.LogitResults.remove_data.html

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1729

Note, the models and results classes maintain a white list for what should be dropped. It could be that in some cases the whitelist is not complete. (In which case a bug report would be appreciated.)

One caveat, patsy's formulas cannot be pickled. So, pickling with or without `remove_data` currently needs to recreate the formulas when it is used, which might not work if the environment does not contain the required information. This is relevant if patsy is used to transform the new data for prediction. It's irrelevant if formulas are not used.

To the last part of the question:
There are currently no standalone predict functions. The predict methods are hardcoded inside the models, or link functions in GLM. So, there is currently no way to predict without creating a model instance. (In the simplest cases, e.g. with just numpy arrays it wouldn't even need to be a model with a full dataset.)

Comment: Sweet! Thanks very much

Comment: I added two more paragraphs on related issues. There would also be a trick like storing the `params` and then creating a fake model with new or artificial data that would work just for simple prediction e.g. `model.predict(params, exog, offset)`. However, that's not unit tested and not "officially" supported.